# How to acces models from tf-models-official? (Module Not Found tensorflow_models)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

I encountered a problem while using the pip Version of the Tensorflow model garden:

The official tutorial supposes following steps:

pip install tensorflow -> Done

pip install tf-models-official -> Done

then running following code:

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow_models import nlp
```

results in following error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_models'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: Its python 3.11

Comment: Have you double check your python environment, just make sure you're using the right Python

Comment: @Rizquuula pretty sure. I am using conda and in terminal pip show tf-models-official shows the installed version. if i try to import in python ant in the same terminal, same Error